# hard Lefschetz isomorphism for rational Tate module

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, abelian-schemes

Let $k$ be a finite field, $\ell \neq \mathrm{char} k$ be prime, $X/k$ be a smooth projective geometrically integral variety of dimension $d$, and $\mathcal{A}/X$ be an Abelian scheme. Let $\eta \in H^2(X,\mathbf{Q}_\ell(1))$ be the first Chern class of $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$.

I want to prove that the hard Lefschetz morphism $\eta^{d-1}: H^1(X,V_\ell\mathcal{A}) \to H^{2d-1}(X,V_\ell\mathcal{A}(d-1))$ is an isomorphism, $V_\ell\mathcal{A}$ the rationalised Tate module of $\mathcal{A}/X$. Using the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence $H^p(G_k,H^q(\bar{X},V_\ell\mathcal{A})) \Rightarrow H^{p+q}(X,V_\ell\mathcal{A})$, I have reduced this to $k$ the algebraic closure of a finite field.

I want to apply [Deligne, Weil II], p. 250, Théorème (6.2.13) http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/grad_2009/Weil-II.pdf.  For this I have to check:

1. $V_\ell\mathcal{A}$ is potentially pure (see [Deligne, Weil II], p. 248, (6.2.8): This means for $(X/S,V_\ell\mathcal{A}), f: X \to S$, $S$ the spectrum of the Henselisation of $k[T]$ in $(T)$:

a) $\mathrm{Spec} k$ is a geometric generic point of an integral scheme $A_0$ of finite type over $\mathbf{Z}[1/\ell]$. [I think we can take $A_0 = \mathrm{Spec}\mathbf{F}_p$ for $p = \mathrm{char} k$.]

b) $S$ comes from scalar extension of $k$, and Henselisation, from a smooth curve $S_0$ over $A_0$ equipped with a section.

c) $f$ comes from a proper morphism $f_0: X_0 \to S_0$. [This should follow from $X/k$ being projective.]

d) $V_\ell\mathcal{A}$ comes from a pure complex $K_0 \in D^b_c(X_0)$. [This should follow since $V_\ell\mathcal{A} = R^1\pi_*\mathbf{Q}_\ell(1)$ for $\pi: \mathcal{A}^t \to X$ the dual Abelian scheme is pure of weight $-1$ by Weil II.]

2. $V_\ell\mathcal{A}$ and $DV_\ell\mathcal{A}[-2d]$ verify the following condition: For every $i$, the dimension of the support of the sheaf $\mathcal{H}^i$ is $\leq d-i$ (set $\mathrm{dim} \emptyset = -\infty$).

Can someone please help me proving these conditions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the question is “Can someone help... “, then “Sure, Beilinson-Bernstein-Deligne can!” seems to be a legitimate answer. Let me write a few words.

The statement you give is a variant of the relative Hard Lefschetz theorem
for pure perverse sheaves — Théorème 5.4.10 in Beilinson-Bernstein-Deligne's paper *Faisceaux pervers* (Astérisque **100**, 1982, Société mathématique de France).

Conditions d) and 2 of Deligne's theorem are equivalent to the hypothesis that $V_\ell(A)[d]$ is pure and perverse, respectively.

Since $\pi\colon\mathcal A\to X$ is an abelian scheme, it is proper and smooth, hence $R^1\pi_*\mathbf Q_\ell$ is a lisse sheaf (proper and smooth base changes). By the Weil conjectures (in this case, Weil's theorem), it is pure of weight $1$. Then $V_\ell\mathcal A$ is its dual; it is lisse, and pure of weight $-1$.

If $L$ is a lisse sheaf on a smooth purely $d$-dimensional variety, then $K=L[d]$ (aka, the complex where $L$ is placed in degree $-d$) is a perverse sheaf. The condition on $\mathcal H^i K$ holds since all groups are zero, except $\mathcal H^{-d}K = L$. The condition on the dual holds as well, because $K^\vee = L^\vee[d]$ and $L^\vee$ is lisse.
(See [BBD] 4.3.1 for a general description of simple perverse sheaves along these lines.)

So, to answer specifically your question, replacing $L$ by $V_\ell\mathcal A$ in the preceding paragraph checks condition 2).

(Edited, twice, to remove inaccuracies and add details)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! Can one find also a proof of condition 2. there (is this the perversity)?

Comment: Yes it is precisely the perversity condition, but it is “hidden” in the language of perverse t-structures - see the statement of 4.2.4 where they study “cohomological amplitude properties” of a morphism.

Comment: Thank you again! I will give you the reputation once I have checked the reference tomorrow!

Comment: I am sorry that I have to ask you again: How exactly does it follow from 4.2.4 that $\pi_!\mathbf{Q}_\ell$ is pure and perverse?

Comment: Part of my answer was nonsense. I corrected it and added details.

Comment: What/where is Gaitsgory's statement? The paragraph "Since $\pi:\mathcal{A} \to X$ ..." is clear to me, but where can I find a proof of the next paragraph "If $L$ is a lisse sheaf ..."? [BBD] 4.3.1 seems to be something different. Is there a statement in [BBD] like "If $f: X \to Y$ is smooth lisse then $R^if_*\mathbf{Q}_\ell$ is pure perverse? Also, regarding Théorème 5.4.10: (why) is ${}^pH^{-i}f_*\mathcal{F}_0 = R^{d-i}f_*\mathcal{F}_0$?

Comment: 1) I had misunderstood your link and thought that you were mentioning a write-up of Weil-II by Gaitsgory.  2) If $f\colon X\to Y$ is smooth and proper, then SGA 4 (smooth/proper base change) says that $R^if_*\mathbf Q_\ell$ is lisse, and Weil II says that it is pure. 3) [BBD 4.3.1] describes all irreducible perverse sheaves - intermediate extension of a lisse sheaf on a (locally closed) geometrically reduced subvariety.

Comment: 4) Since $f$ is proper and smooth, $Rf_*\mathcal F_0$ is a perfect complex (lisse cohomologies). Its perverse cohomology groups, associated with the perverse $t$-structure, are given by decomposing it using the $t$-structure axiom. You build it degree by degree by the given formula.

Comment: I found a proof of $L$ lisse on $X$ smooth pure-$d$-dimensional => $L[d]$ perverse in [Kiehl-Weissauer], p. 149, Corollary III.5.5 (or in http://www.mathematik.uni-regensburg.de/Jannsen/home/Garben-gesamt-engproof.pdf p. 76f., Theorem 11.14).

Comment: That's probably a good reference but I don't know that book well.